# What happened to Gendry?

Tags: game-of-thrones

In *Game of Thrones* we have seen Gendry the bastard of Robert Baratheon who browed away from Dragonstone, apparently never to be seen again. Where did he go? From season 3.

Comment: How would we know? Like you said: nothing has been shown.

Comment: He should be on DragonStone only then.

Comment: Gendry just browed away from Dragonstone then how he could be on DragonStone.

Comment: Do you want to know what happen to him in the books or what was hinted in the show?

Comment: This site is about the show only. The differences are huge already.

Comment: @BCdotWEB it's possible there could be some info in, say, an interview with an actor or member of the production team, or a deleted scene, or a supplementary source set in the same world like the Telltale Games series

Comment: It's pretty clear that they had no function for him in the post-S3 storylines and thus they came up with a way out. One less actor wage to pay, one less pawn to keep track of. They kept it open-ended just in case they might "need" him later on, but until such a thing happens you ain't going to hear anything definite. [The actor knows nothing either.](http://www.wetpaint.com/where-is-gendry-joe-dempsie-829668/)

Comment: @BCdotWEB that sounds like an answer to the question, with a solid source to back it up

Comment: ["*Still rowin'...*"](https://twitter.com/joedempsie/status/479055824414076928)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is purely speculation, considering [the actor didn't know anything about his character's future a year ago (June 2014)](http://www.wetpaint.com/where-is-gendry-joe-dempsie-829668/).

**BEWARE:** spoilers for **all** of *Game of Thrones* in the upcoming text.

Here's the problem: by the end of the third series Gendry's role was basically superfluous. Even worse, considering what would happen by the end of season five -- i.e. the death of Shireen -- this character was a hindrance: why would Stannis sacrifice his daughter when there was a Baratheon bastard still available? And if his execution didn't do the trick, then burning Shireen would not have anywhere near the same emotional impact.

So why not have him executed by Melisandre, like she wished for (at the end of season three)? That would severely impact the character of Stannis, and they need him to be the big hero who saves the day at The Wall in season four. Moreover, there's a small chance Gendry has a role later on: in the books he's still around, even though he's in a completely different place. I wouldn't rule out a Gendry-Arya reunion.

By having Gendry escape from the cells and [row into the darkness at the end of the season](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Gendry#Season_3), as arranged by Davos Seaworth, they have a great solution: if they need him in the future, he can pop up somewhere convenient. And if they don't, well, then we can assume he has drown -- the likely outcome considering he cannot swim and had never rowed a boat.

Considering the producers aren't shy of confirming deaths when the fandom had come up with alternatives -- e.g. Stannis, Myrcella -- I can only interpret their silence about Gendry's fate as them keeping their options open. But in the meantime they don't have to pay the actor, and they don't have to worry about keeping track of yet another character.

Answer (score 5):

Speculation is over - Gendry is back in Season 7 ... [though no-one is saying what he will be doing, of course]

From [Radio Times - This Game of Thrones actor showed up to the premiere and basically confirmed his long-awaited return
Row row row your boat - guess who's BACK in Westeros?](http://www.radiotimes.com/news/2017-07-13/this-game-of-thrones-actor-showed-up-to-the-premiere-and-basically-confirmed-his-long-awaited-return)

Comment: With only six episodes left in the series, I wonder how big a part he will play in the endgame